# Android NDK app won't run

Tags: android-ndk

I've been trying to get started on adding native code to my android app so I've looked through a plethora of Android NDK tutorials all to no avail. I can't get any of the apps to run on my emulator or my Galaxy S3. I keep getting the same error: "Unfortunately, [AppName] has stopped working"
My ndk-build command works successfully and I get a .so file. I don't know what the .so file is supposed to look like. Here's mine

http://txt.do/klo0

it looks like gibberish to me but what do I know?

This is my logcat
http://txt.do/klod

Comment: Obviously, problem is stated here: `Native method not found: com.example.ndksetup.NDKSetupActivity.printLog`. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) to solve it? Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's a programming website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ndk app stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517066/android-ndk-app-stops-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android NDK directory, there is a hello-jni example. Try to compile and run it, it works.

It's in the `samples/hello-jni` directory of your NDK, I have it in `~/android-ndk-r9d/samples/hello-jni`. Copy ("import") it into your workspace and compile.

To generate the headers:

```
cd bin/classes
javah com.my.package.name.MyClassName
```

Note that the library is usually placed by `ndk-build` into the `libs/something` subdirectory of your project, for example, `libs/armeabi-v7a`, and the file `jni/Application.mk` specifies what `something` is, e.g.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

or

```
APP_ABI := all
```

The library will be placed in your apk and installed in a subdirectory of your application's data folder.

```
System.loadLibrary("stuff"); // libstuff.so
```

will find it.  (Note that if you run your app as a system app, that's a different story.)

A library built for a wrong target will not work.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix little errors by looking through the sample code