# Android ndk app stops working

Tags: android-ndk

I've been trying to get started on adding native code to my android app so I've looked through a plethora of Android NDK tutorials all to no avail. I can't get any of the apps to run on my emulator or my Galaxy S3. I keep getting the same error: "Unfortunately, [AppName] has stopped working"
My ndk-build command works successfully and I get a .so file. I don't know what the .so file is supposed to look like. Here's mine

http://txt.do/klo0

it looks like gibberish to me but what do I know?

This is my logcat
http://txt.do/klod
It says `Native Method Not Found`

I have the following code as my main (and only) activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NDKSetupActivity extends Activity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("ndksetup");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    printLog("Hello!!");
}

private native void printLog(String logThis);
}
```

This is my C code (called native.c)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDKSetupActivity"

void com_example_ndksetup_NDKSetupActivity_printLog(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jstring logString)
{
jboolean isCopy;
const char * szLogString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logString, &isCopy);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK: %s", szLogString);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logString, szLogString);
}
```

This is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndksetup
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is my Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ndksetup"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".NDKSetupActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the Java package name and where is the java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **`Java_`** prefix. Try renaming the function name in `native.c` to `Java_com_example_ndksetup_NDKSetupActivity_printLog`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For correct function names, there's `javah`:

```
cd bin/classes
javah com.company.MyClassWithNativeStuff com.company.Util
```

It generates .h files.